# MySQL trigger to update a column a from value of column b when an entry is inserted

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I am trying to update the value of the contractnum which should be empty when something gets inserted into table1. I want to update it to whatever field2 has which is always a unique number.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER database1.Update_Contract_Num
BEFORE INSERT ON database1.table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
/*Update contract Num when new doc gets inserted and copy the contents of field1*/
IF contractnum IS NULL THEN
SET CONTRACTNUM = field2
END IF
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax problems:

1. You need to use the `NEW` prefix to reference the column values of the row being inserted
2. You need to terminate some of the lines with semi-colons

This should be closer to what you need:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER database1.Update_Contract_Num
BEFORE INSERT ON database1.table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  /*Update contract Num when new doc gets inserted and copy the contents of field1*/
  IF NEW.contractnum IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.CONTRACTNUM = NEW.field2;
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am kind of new at this SQl Triggers and I knew it was something with the syntax. I tried it in so many different ways.  Thank you!!!